# How to use same instance of ViewModel in activity as well as fragment?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

I have created an instance of ViewModel in **MainActivity** and setup an observer. I want the observed data into one of the fragments of MainActivity's ViewPager. How can I get the required **LiveData** into the **fragment**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using AndroidX extension delegate

In the MainActivity:

```
private val activityViewModel: SomeViewModel by viewModels()
```

In the Fragement

```
private val activityViewModel: SomeViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

With ViewModelFactory, put the ViewModelFactory intance into closure

```
private val activityViewModel: SomeViewModel by viewModels{ viewModelFactory }
private val activityViewModel: SomeViewModel by activityViewModels{ viewModelFactory}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use shared ViewModel
[Shared ViewModel between activity and fragments](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjt0Kf-uZfqAhVKWxUIHbhRC8kQFjAAegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftopic%2Flibraries%2Farchitecture%2Fviewmodel&usg=AOvVaw3f_7HpGuQps9xX6BXFMqhB)

for this you can define an object from activity's viewModel in your fragment with activity as viewModel's owner and apply changes on that's variables.